# Newbie green screener: background keyed out without selecting key color

Tags: chromakey

Newbie here: I’ve been through several green screen tuts, think I understand it, but am not getting the results shown in the tuts. Using v2.82.7 and v2.83.1 after reinstalling to try to fix problem. I have gone into compositing, opened the source file in the movie clip node, added the composite node, and viewer node. All works as expected. I see the source image in the background of compositing window. ***As soon as I add*** the matte keying node, the image looses its background, as if I had selected the background keying color…though I didn’t. The keying color remains set to the default white. The original background, which disappears, it blue. Without making any entries into the keying node, the background disappears. I’ve set up a virgin model for testing, and without any changes to the model at all, the background disappears the instant I add the keying node. Any idea why this is happening? Note 1.Blue background in image clip node. 2.Default white key color in keying node. 3.Missing background in viewer node. Thanks for any help.

[image: Node arrangement.]

Comment: What to you need the matte for? What else will you do with the image? Please explain.

Comment: If I understand your question: the tutorials on chroma key that I'm following all use the matte key node, which seems easier than one of the other key methods, due to the richness of the options. It is just not acting as the tuts describe. If it is relevant; I have not created a matte in this example.